# Need help on CSS inline alignment in Servicenow

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new and learning front end.

I created a simple form contains `4 fields`. how to align all these in line equally divided?

below is my code written on `HTML` along with the output what i see:

```html
<div>
 <form>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
         <label>Name:   </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" >
   </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label>Email:   </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" >
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label>Phone #:   </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label>Education Qualificiation:   </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" >
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

[Output above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAZDg.png)

Comment: so you need 4 different rows where it is aligned correctly?

Comment: Do you want a single row where all the 4 fields are evenly distributed?

Comment: @Manjuboyz No, i want 2 rows in the first row i want to display Name and Email and second row i want Phone and Education fields. I am getting the correct output only problem is if you see the output it is dynaminc moving based on the label name. I want it to be static

Comment: @Tushar No Sir i want in 2 rows evenly distributed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/4k8gd3ym/7/) to validate

```css
.lblClass {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <form>
    <div class="form-inline d-flex">
      <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex">
        <label class="lblClass">Name:   </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex">
        <label class="lblClass">Email:   </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex">
        <label class="lblClass">Phone #:   </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex">
        <label class="lblClass">Education Qualificiation:   </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked nicely. but can you please help me how to increase the text box width to little more ?

Comment: here you go, since it is BS we have to override exiting property: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/4k8gd3ym/18/

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to align element. But here you are uses bootstrap and bootstrap have predefined classes for align element. You want to align elements in the form so bootstrap have Form-group, form control class for your all. Problems
Visit this link for more info
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/